# Snapcraft and .sh

Tags: packaging, snap

How can I tell Snapcraft to run a `.sh` file before `make`? I know I have to use the `after` command in the yaml file but how do I make Snapcraft run the `.sh` file?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you're on Xenial using Snapcraft v2.24 (the latest as of this writing).

Say you have the following Makefile:

```
all:
        @touch built

install:
        @cp prepared $(DESTDIR)/
        @cp built $(DESTDIR)/
        @touch $(DESTDIR)/installed
```

The following shell script (called `prepare.sh`, make sure it's executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

touch prepared
```

As well as the following `snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: test-snap
version: '0.1'
summary: summary
description: description
grade: devel
confinement: strict

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: make
    # The `prepare` keyword specifies what should happen before this
    # part is built (i.e. in this case before `make` is run). It
    # consists of shell commands.
    prepare: |
      ./prepare.sh
```

Put them all in the same directory, and run `snapcraft prime`. After it's completed, you'll see three files in the `prime/` directory (other than the `meta/` directory): `prepared` (generated by the shell script and installed by the Makefile), `built` (generated and installed by the Makefile) and `installed` (generated and installed by the Makefile).

Would using the `prepare` keyword work for your use-case?

Comment: Hi Kyle, thank you for your answer but it did not work. In the end i figured out how to use the dump command instead. So I have now done all I need whit sh and make before I try to snap.  The application works fine after i do sh and make but after I snap it wont work. I have been working with this for over a week now and well I will give up now. I am tired of SNAP.  But in any case I was trying to make a snap of unreal 4. Have a good day.